# Using a multi-statement view in an indexed view

Tags: sql-server

Is is possible? If yes, how?

Here's the error message I get when trying to create it:
Cannot create index on view "*view name*" because it references the inline or multistatement table-valued function "*function name*". Consider expanding the function definition by hand in the view definition, or not indexing the view.

Comment: No this isn't possible. There are many restrictions even on single statement queries before they can be used in an indexed view. What does your multistatement tvf do?

Comment: See the "View Restrictions" section of [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120) for a good list of things that are not allowed in an indexed view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this list and determine whether your view passes all checkpoints:

- The ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER options must have been set to ON
  when the CREATE VIEW statement was executed. The OBJECTPROPERTY
  function reports this for views through the ExecIsAnsiNullsOn or
  ExecIsQuotedIdentOn properties.

  The ANSI_NULLS option must have been set to ON for the execution of
  all CREATE TABLE statements that create tables referenced by the
  view.

  The view must not reference any other views, only base tables.

  All base tables referenced by the view must be in the same database
  as the view and have the same owner as the view.

  The view must be created with the SCHEMABINDING option. Schema
  binding binds the view to the schema of the underlying base tables.

  **User-defined functions referenced in the view must have been created
  with the SCHEMABINDING option**.

  **Tables and user-defined functions must be referenced by two-part
  names in the view. One-part, three-part, and four-part names are not
  allowed.**

  **All functions referenced by expressions in the view must be
  deterministic.** The IsDeterministic property of the OBJECTPROPERTY
  function reports whether a user-defined function is deterministic.
  For more information, see Deterministic and Nondeterministic
  Functions.

Source: [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)

Comment: Not sure what rationale you are using to bold the text here? The relevant bit is surely **The view must not reference any other views, only base tables.**